# compare block disappears from sidebar

Tags: magento-1.9, sidebar, compare

I see when there is no item selected to compare, the block-compare is not displaying in sidebar and after adding product to compare it is there. How to display this block always and show message"You have not selected any items to compare" for example?

Answer (score 1):

Natively the block should show regardless, and if there's no item, it would say "You have no items to compare.". So it looks like your theme is customised, or a module overwrites it. Make sure your `catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml` in your theme folder is similar to the default one.

Comment: Even I copied the sidebar.phtml from default to my theme folder, still I can not see the block :(

Answer (score 0):

The core code will *not* display the block if there's no recently compared products:

```
protected function _toHtml()
{
    if (!$this->getCount()) {
        return '';
    }

    $this->setRecentlyComparedProducts($this->getItemsCollection());

    return parent::_toHtml();
}
```

To change this behavior you can do a rewrite of the `Mage_Reports_Block_Product_Compared` block to fulfill your needs.

Comment: This is for the "Recently Compared Products" block, that doesn't apply here

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. In default sidebar.phtml there is a line $_items = $_helper->getItemCount() > 0 ? $_helper->getItemCollection() : null; I removed the condition of checking $_items and it works now.

Comment: Can you paste the content of your `sidebar.phtml`, your solution isn't really one.